# What are the trusted Certificate Authorities in iOS?

Tags: ios, certificate, mobile-mail

I'm wondering if [StartCom](http://www.startcom.org/) is a trusted CA on iOS.

I'd like to setup a mail server for a TLD, and use their free certificate. It's only about $10/year cheaper than more well known authorities, so the deciding factor is if it's trusted on my iPhone.

I know it is on OS X, Windows and many linux distributions, but would like to be certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this Apple support article has the list you're looking for. It is updated as changes are made:

[iOS: List of available trusted root certificates](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5012)

And StartCom is on there.

Comment: This link goes to iOS 8 now.

Comment: @Almo I edited my question and this answer to make it less prone to obsolescence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the trust list for iOS 7:

http://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT203065